# how to get sender email address and name in nodejs ? Am using Nodemailer

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

I have nodemailer code and it all works fine. I can see my message but in my  mail inbox, I see that I have sent mail to myself. I need to get sender email address which is in my contact form. Here is my code

```
var data = new Object();
var mailData = {
    from: this.request.body.email, //grab form data from the request body object,
    to: 'myemail@gmail.com',
    subject: 'koa test email',
    text: this.request.body.message
};
```

and  am also using myemail@gmail.com as auth and pass.

Comment: I don't understand, are you using myemail@gmail.com as the from and to email addresses? Also share your whole route handler